# How to import sqlite3 in my python3.4 successfully?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.4

There are two python version in my debian7, one is python2.7 the system default version, the other is python3.4 which compiled to install this way.

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
 apt-get install build-essential
 wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/Python-3.4.0.tgz
 tar -zxvf Python-3.4.0.tgz
 cd Python-3.4.0
 mkdir /usr/local/python3.4
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.4
 make
 make install
 ln -s /usr/local/python3.4/bin/python3.4   /usr/bin/python3.4
 ln -s /usr/local/python3.4/bin/pip3.4   /usr/bin/pip3.4
```

I have installed sqlite this way on my debian.

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

In python2.7

```
root@rebuild:~# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
```

In python3.4

```
root@rebuild:~# python3.4
Python 3.4.0 (default, Nov 27 2014, 13:54:17)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

How can i import sqlite3 in my python3.4 successfully?

Comment: What did you expect? If you install `sqlite3` via your package manager it will only be compiled for your Python installations installed in the same way. Have you tried something like `./configure --with-sqlite`?

Comment: i can import sqlite3 in python2.7, how can i import it in my python3.4?

Comment: think for  filmor . apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev and recompile to install python with  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.4  --with-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same swamped to this problem, this flow success in oracel-linux/python3

1.Download and install [sqlite3](https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-autoconf-3180000.tar.gz)

```
$ tar sqlite-autoconf-3180000.tar.gz  
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3180000  
$./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sqlite3 && make && make install
```

2.Export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

3.Download and install [python3.6](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz)

```
$ tar Python-3.6.0.tar.xz  
$ cd Python-3.6.0  
$ ./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. I already had python installed before the trying to update to the newest version of sqlite3. So I compiled it and then made sure to run the export in my virtualenv active file.

Answer (score 2):

From the information provided and order presented, it looks like you installed python 3.4 from source BEFORE making installing the sqlite-dev package available.  If you watch the python 3.4 install closely you would have noticed any number of modules it did not build out (one of which would be _sqlite3).

Solution: Reinstall 3.4 now that sqlite3 dev is available.