# ImportError: No Module Named 'pysqlite2'

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, debian

I have written a program in Python which was done on windows. And in the windows test environment worked fine. Now I am setting up a linux server to internally host the program. I have installed all the dependencies etc from a generated requirements file but when I run it I come on a problem,

```
ImportError: No Module Named 'pysqlite2'.
```

I have extensively googled this issue and have not found a solution. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem from code below? I cannot upload an image due to reputation isnt high enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any other information is needed just comment and I will upload.

```
File "/home/ryan/python_p/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 334, in dbapi
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
ImportError: No Module named 'pysqlite2'
```

As far as I understand it sqlite either is not compatible or has compatibility issues?

Another issue that I think is directly related is when inside the virtual environment and I try pip3.4 install pysqlite i get

```
SyntaxError: Missing Parenthesis in call to 'Print
```

Its suggests install Sphinx which I did but did not cure.

I think these two issues are directly related and by curing ine should be able to cure the other.

Comment: Can you paste here a `pip freeze` of the enviorment in your linux server enviorment?

Comment: Babel==1.3
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Babel==0.9
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.11
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.3.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.9
Tempita==0.5.2
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
WTForms==2.0.2
Werkzeug==0.10.4
Whoosh==2.6.0
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
argparse==1.2.1
blinker==1.3
chardet==2.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
coverage==3.7.1
decorator==3.4.2
flipflop==1.0
guess-language==0.2
html5lib==0.999
itsdangerous==0.24
pbr==0.10.8
pexpect==3.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycurl==7.19.3
pygobject==3.12.0
pyserial==2.6

Comment: python-apt==0.9.3.5
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
pytz==2015.2
pyxdg==0.25
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.2.1
six==1.9.0
speaklater==1.3
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.9.6
sqlparse==0.1.15
system-service==0.1.6
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.7.1
virtualenv==12.1.1
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xdiagnose==3.6.3build2
zope.interface==4.0.5

Comment: do you have sqlite3 installed in your python3.4? can you open a shell and run import sqlite3?

Comment: SQLite3 is installed but it is preinstalled with Debian. I can call $sqlite3 but I cannot call it from within Python. When inside the virtual environment I can do sudo apt-get install sqlite3 and I get confirmation that the latest sqlite3 is installed. How do I got about including to be called from Python?

Comment: I think the problem may be that SQLite3 is not a requiremtn in the Virtual Environment and therefor cant be imported. Ive tried installing it while in the virtual environment but it just confirms that it exists already and is up to date. which sqlite3 returns /usr/local/bin/sqlite3, should installing it within the environment location cure the issue?

Comment: The problem is sqlite3 is a standard library for python but if your python installation cannot detect it because sqlite3 is not available then you could try `pip install pysqlite`

Comment: As mentioned above when I do this i get an error Missing Parenthesis in call to 'print'. It suggests installing sphinx but this does not cure the issue. I think this error may be because sqlite is not available for Python 3 yet.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt see that before, damn, that error means you cant install that into python3.x

Comment: Ok, so basically you cant install it, and sqlite3 should be a standard library in your python3.4 So you have a problem with your python3.4 installation. Check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470530/how-to-import-sqlite3-in-my-python3-4-successfully

Comment: lapinkoira your a saviour. That cured the issue and it is now running. Thanks a million

Comment: `pip install pysqlite3` does it

Answer (score 5):

You can do the below changes to make your jupyter notebook work

Replace the file “C:\Windows\System32\sqlite3.dll”
by “C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin\sqlite3.dll”

This will make jupyter notebook work

Answer (score 3):

You could probably just use `sqlite3` which is now part of the standard library and should work exactly the same as pysqlite2 does. You can try to modify the file mentioned from:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

to

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

Comment: need to install sqlite3 ?

Comment: alternatively you can try to do a `pip install pysqlite2`

Comment: Tried modifying the pysqlite.py to read from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite. This does not change it still gives me the same error and I have verified that I altered the correct file etc.

Comment: If it raises `No Module named 'pysqlite2'` Then there has to be an import for it somewhere

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I am having similar issues. I installed python3 with home-brew. Now when I try to import sqlite 3, i get similar error. I have sqlite3 installed. Just can't import it inside python3.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip search sqlite`, you may find many candidates. Pick something like this one:

```
 pip install pysqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

For people on CentOS 6 and Python 2.6:

Executing `pip install pysqlite` directly would result in a gcc error, you would have to `yum install sqlite-devel` first, before installing pysqlite.

After that, `ImportError` may still persist, if you are using a Python version different from the Python 2.6 that's shipped with CentOS 6. The error message I got is like:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_stmt_readonly
```

This is a linking issue, copying below *compiled library files* from old Py2.6 directory to Py2.7 solved my problem, as inspired by [this](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/issues/85#issuecomment-299443937) Github discussion.

```sh
cp /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/
cp /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with multiple python dependent package while setup, specifically while installing jupyter notebook in python virtual enironment in **Ubuntu**.It is because of **sqlite** binding for our **python**.

**Error I got**:

```
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

I resolved it by --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions=yes
1.) First find your python or python version you used for creating virtual env. I have used python3.8
e.g

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.8-config  python

$ cd /usr/bin

$ls
python3.8
python3.8-config
```

**Note:** there will be many package check for pytho. you will find configure file for each python version, now use specific python version

```
ox:/usr/bin$ ./python3.8-config --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions=yes
```

OR

```
ox:/usr/bin$ ./python3.8-config --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
```

Now, create your virtual env using that python version
e.g
Go the folder where you want to create the virtual env

```
$ python3.8 -m venv mlwen_jup_env
$ source mlwen_jup_env/bin/activate
```

Its done, now you can install packages

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me

```
pip install notebook
```