# How do I resolve ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3' and No module named 'pysqlite2' python 3.5

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, pysqlite

Installing jupyter notebook from [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/install.html)

Python3 version

```
Python 3.5.2
```

pip list

```
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.2.3)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
```

Running jupyter notebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Also tried sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev from [No module named _sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3)

How to resolve the above error?

Comment: What platform are you on? For linux, make sure you have sqlite dev package installed; e.g. libsqlite3-dev on debian/ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770906/importerror-no-module-named-pysqlite2

Comment: @kaveh I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and I already installed libsqlite3-dev.

Comment: @MaazBinMusa It's read-only file located in /usr/local/lib/..

Answer (score 1):

To fix the import error for `_sqlite3` I did the following:

- Installed `libsqlite3-dev` on my Ubuntu 18.04
- Installed `Python 2.7.15` following https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint.

After this `python -c 'import _sqlite3'` succeeded when I used the alternate installation in `/usr/local/bin/python`.  I believe you can install Python3 from the source like this and use it.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. Apparently pyton2.7 in Ubuntu 18.10 repositories has been built with no sqlite support