ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2' when I run jupyter notebook
I'm using debian 12
I created a virtual environment using virtualenv in ~/.venv
Then I installed jupyter notebook with pip install jupyter
Now I run jupyter notebook and it throws this error
(.venv) marcelaar@marcel:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcelaar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcelaar/.venv/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.app import main
  File "/home/marcelaar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.serverapp import flags
  File "/home/marcelaar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 107, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.gateway.managers import (
  File "/home/marcelaar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/gateway/managers.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ..services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/marcelaar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3  # type:ignore[no-redef]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

I also tried to install pysqlite2 with pip install pysqlite2 but I got
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysqlite2


Even I tried to open the python interpreter of the virtual environment and import by myself pysqlite2 and sqlite3 modules. I found in internet that sqlite3 comes by default with python but I got an error when I imported sqlite3
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
>>> 

I just want to open jupyter notebook without problems
Thanks for any help!

related, but imo not a duplicate (doesn't have a definite Answer and none of the existing ones look like a good fit) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770906/importerror-no-module-named-pysqlite2

have you a similar issue with other packages, such as os, tkinter?

with which configuration have you installed python? Show the output of import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('CONFIG_ARGS')[0])




print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('CONFIG_ARGS')[0])
'--enable-shared' '--prefix=/usr' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions' '--with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm' '--with-computed-gotos' '--without-ensurepip' '--with-system-expat' '--with-dtrace' '--with-wheel-pkg-dir=/usr/share/python-wheels/' '--with-ssl-default-suites=openssl' 'MKDIR_P=/bin/mkdir -p' '--with-system-ffi' 'CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' 'CFLAGS=-g   -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=  -g -fwrapv -O2   ' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'




I was using anaconda as package manager, so installing pysqlite3 package resolved the notebook issue for me.
