# No module named _sqlite3 for scrapyd

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm new bie to Python who is stucked in the need of recompilation of Python.

I have server with Centos where I have installed Python3.6 and then scrapyd. Everything installed successfully, however when I try to run scrapyd command, it shows me below error:

[image]

After search a while, I got to know that sqlite3 should be installed even before Python3.6, however I have installed sqlite3 now but now found that I need recompile the Python.

So, Above is the situation, now I have a question that, is that the case where I needed to install sqlite3 and recompile the Python? If yes then how I can recompile Python? If no then how can I get rid of this issue and can start the scrapyd?

Help is really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you'll need to re-install the python version as per this as actually the sqlite3 is the extension which should be install before Python gets installed.

Please check this -

> [How to import sqlite3 in my python3.4 successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470530/how-to-import-sqlite3-in-my-python3-4-successfully)

Comment: Thank you for your reply djtechie..Actually I have already spent a lot of time for configuring all the stuff and I've to re-install scrapyd too which will be again time investing. So, if any quick solution is there then it will be really helpful.

Comment: After digging a lot, I have found that the only way is to re-install the Python. I have done that and the problem resolved. So, can consider that the only way is re-installation.